# Настройка Webpack и Pug, как правильно указать src для image

Tags: webpack, pug

Уже пол дня не могу настроить *правильные пути* для картинок в pug файлах, мне кажется я что-то не понимаю или упускаю из виду.

В src использую require() и указываю относительный путь

```
img(src=require('../../../assets/img/logo/logo.svg'), alt='Логотип')
```

Картинки он находит и добавляет в папку dist, все как положено.

**НО** немного странно записывает путь для них после преобразования в html

```
<img src="{&quot;default&quot;:&quot;/images/logo.svg&quot;}" alt="Логотип">
```

В DevTools это выглядит так:

[image: DevTools]

```
{
    test: /\.pug$/, 
    loader: 'pug-loader',
    options: {
        pretty: isDev
    }
},
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif)$/, 
    loader: 'file-loader', 
    options:{
        name: filename('[name]','[ext]'), // filename = (name, ext) => isDev ? `${name}.${ext}` : `${name}.[hash].${ext}`;
        outputPath :  '/images/',
    }
},
```

Естественно **картинки не подгружаются**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно указывать

> require(относительный путь).default

```
img(src=require('../../../assets/img/logo/logo.svg').default, alt='Логотип')
```

И все заработает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]